# navigate,pop, reset in react native outside of react component using NavigationService

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm going to use `react navigation` outside of react component so I don't have access to props, I could do this for `navigate` but I don't know how to implement it for `reset` and `pop` this is my code for `navigate`:

```
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params,
        })
    );
}

export default {
    navigate,
    setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this you can use navigate, pop, reset:

refrence:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html

```
import {NavigationActions, StackActions} from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params,
        })
    );
}

function reset(routeName, params) {
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
        index: 0, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName, params})]
    });
    _navigator.dispatch(resetAction);
}

function pop(n = 1) {
    const popAction = StackActions.pop({
        n,
    });

    _navigator.dispatch(popAction);
}

export default {
    navigate,
    pop,
    reset,
    setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Import StackActions in NavigationService**

```
import {
  NavigationActions,
  StackActions,
} from "react-navigation";
```

**Add function for pop and replace**

```
function replace(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    StackActions.replace({
      routeName,
      params
    })
  );
}

function pop(number = 1) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    StackActions.pop({
      n: number
    })
  );
}
```

**Note: Pop has parameter how many screens to pop . Default is 1 means current screen**